# area between two parallel chords

Tags: geometry

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7r09.jpg)
Assume we got a scenario in the picture. I want to calculate the area between two chords with angles theta1 and theta2. Could anyone suggest me how to calculate it based on the angles and distance defined in the picture?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Hint: the area of  a *segment* of a circle, i.e., the area above the chord, is $A_{segment}=\frac{1}{2}R^2(\theta-\sin\theta)$, where $\theta$ is as shown in your figure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, all angles here are in **RADIANS** not degrees.

Given: $O$ denotes the center of the circle,
$ R $ is the radius of the circle, $\theta_1 $ is the angle in the upper triangle opposite to the upper chord , $ \theta_2$ is the angle of the lower triangle opposite to the lower chord

Let $A$ be the leftmost point of intersection b/w the lower chord and the circle, $B$ be the rightmost P.O.I, $C$ be the leftmost P.O.I for the upper and $D$ be the rightmost P.O.I for the upper:

[image: Geogebra Drawing]

The area we are looking for is the Area of the Green shaded Region, 
Let $A_{green}$ be the Area we are looking for.

$A_{green} = A_{⌓AGB} - A_{⌓CGD}$:

[image: Area of Segments b/w chords]

First find $A_{⌓AGB}$

$ A_{⌓AGB} = A_{⌔OAB} - A_{△OAB}$ :
[image: Area of Circular Segment]

And use the same formula to find $A_{⌓CGD}$

$ A_{⌓CGD} = A_{⌔OCD} - A_{△OCD}$: 
[image: Area of Segment]

Thus, $A_{green} = A_{⌓AGB} - A_{⌓CGD} = A_{⌔OAB} - A_{△OAB} - (A_{⌔OCD} - A_{△OCD})$

$ = A_{⌔OAB} - A_{△OAB} - A_{⌔OCD} + A_{△OCD}$

$$ A_{⌔OAB} = \pi R^2 \big(\frac{\theta_2}{2\pi}) = \frac{R^2(\theta_2)}{2}$$ 
$$ A_{⌔OCD} = \pi R^2 \big(\frac{\theta_1}{2\pi}) = \frac{R^2(\theta_1)}{2}$$

You can use trigonometry to find the area of the triangles, $A_{△OAB}$ and $ A_{△OCD}$ : 
[image: Area Of triangles]

$$ A_{△OAB} = R^2(\sin(\frac{\theta_2}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta_2}{2})) $$
 $$ A_{△OCD} = R^2(\sin(\frac{\theta_1}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta_1}{2}))$$

and $A_{green} = A_{⌔OAB} - A_{△OAB} - A_{⌔OCD} + A_{△OCD}$

$$ = \frac{R^2(\theta_2)}{2} - \frac{R^2(\theta_1)}{2} - R^2(\sin(\frac{\theta_2}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta_2}{2})) + R^2(\sin(\frac{\theta_1}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta_1}{2})) $$

$$ = \frac{R^2(\theta_2-\theta_1)}{2} + R^2[(\sin(\frac{\theta_1}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta_1}{2}))-(\sin(\frac{\theta_2}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta_2}{2}))] $$

Recall the compound angle formulas:
$$ \sin \left(A+B\right)=\sin A\cos B+\sin B\cos A $$
$$ \sin \left(A-B\right)=\sin A\cos B-\sin B\cos A $$
$$ \sin(2A) = \sin(A+A) =\sin A\cos A+\sin A\cos A = 2\sin A\cos A $$
$$ \frac{\sin(2A)}{2} = \sin A\cos A $$

Thus, 
$$ (\sin(\frac{\theta_1}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta_1}{2}))-(\sin(\frac{\theta_2}{2})\cos(\frac{\theta_2}{2})) =  \frac{\sin(2(\frac{\theta_1}{2}))}{2} - \frac{\sin(2(\frac{\theta_2}{2}))}{2} $$
$$ = \frac{\sin(\theta_1)}{2} - \frac{\sin(\theta_2)}{2} = \frac{\sin(\theta_1) - \sin(\theta_2)}{2} $$

Therefore

$$ A_{green} = \frac{R^2[\theta_2 -\sin(\theta_2) -\theta_1 + \sin(\theta_1)]}{2} $$